# Using jquery animation angular 5 animation way(for smooth scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular5, angular-animations, angular2-animation

I am using jquery for smooth scroll this way

```
 $('.parent-class').animate({
  scrollTop: $('#scrllhere').offset().top + 10
}, 800);
```

Goal here is on click, i am calling one function based on certain condition i am using above code for  scroll this is working fine but i want to achieve same using angular 5 animation without using jquery.

my function is like this

```
  smoothScroll(){
        $('.parent-class').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#scrllhere').offset().top + 10
    }, 800);

  }
```

Now i want to achieve same thing without using jquery

After going through angular5 animation docs https://angular.io/guide/animations

I am little confused how to use animate() on the fly for scrolling 
Note that there is no state change involved just scrolling

Edit: Even solution in Javascript without using jquery is fine.

Thanks